# Entity Framework code-first : rename table column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Using C# and Visual Studio, I have created a database using the code-first methodology with a table called `Movies`. In this table, I have a column called `name`. This was derived from my C# class. Unfortunately like a tool I misspelled `name` and it should have been `Name`.

I only discovered this after several migrations to the database. I have rolled back to the appropriate migration, just before I created the table `Movie` (contains `name` and `Id`), and changed `name` to `Name`.

Unfortunately I have no idea as to how I can change the C# class field name  `name` to `Name`. If I do and try and update the database I get

> The project 'projectName' failed to build.

I've checked and there are no dependencies or foreign keys relying on this field.

Advice on how to resolve this would be great. Just looking for the outlining steps.

Comment: Failed to build would mean, where ever you used that field would throw an error because, when you previously used `.name` you should now be using `.Name` so check your solution files

Comment: @Mike J use the refactor to rename the field name

Comment: Usually rename the field is not a problem. You had not necessary do roll back. You just need to change the field name in the class and generate migration through the console in the Visual Studio.

Comment: Well a rename has most certainly fixed the issue - however for anyone else reading this i only renamed the field after i had rolled back and changed the field name. I then updated the database and then renamed the field. Of note - rename was done using the rename option not simply change the field and save.